# Why does "c#-to-vb.net" not work in URL?

Tags: support, tags

**Edit:** I've since realized what a dummy I am for missing such an obvious detail.  I've chosen to leave this question here for posterity (I guess).

When I go to this URL:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c#-to-vb.net?page=1&sort=newest&pagesize=100
```

it shows "questions tagged" > `C`.  Why does it show `C` and not `c#-to-vb.net` tagged questions, as specified in the URL?

Comment: Because # denotes a hash fragment...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier

Comment: Okay, I didn't know that.  Why the down vote though?

Comment: For the same reasons as on SO itself: this question does not show enough research effort, and is not particularily useful.

Comment: @l4mpi -- I've been researching the sh#t out of this for days.  Should I have said that in my question?

Comment: @l4mpi -- Also, why isn't it useful?  It's certainly useful to me since that's the primary way I use SO (with tagged URL to filter questions).

Comment: You've been researching that and have not come across the term "url encoding", and neither have considered yourself that there are characters in an URL that might be special? That sounds really unbelieveable, and even if it is true, being bad at research doesn't mean you're exempt from researching.

Comment: @l4mpi -- I know about URL encoding, and now that it has been pointed out to me, I duly feel like a dope.  But haven't you ever looked at a problem from the wrong angle, only to have someone point out a simple solution?  That's what this site is here for, no?

Comment: Yeah, but it's the equivalent of a typo question on SO - you've had a brainfart and once you realize it the question becomes trivial. As long as you can't prove that (a) your use case of creating SO URLs by hand is common and (b) many people don't know about URL encoding or similarily forget about it, I'll stand by my assertion that this question is not particularily useful. Also, you don't exactly have to worry about downvotes on meta as they don't affect your rep.

Comment: @l4mpi Okay, so -- learning opportunity for me -- if I realize a question is just a brain fart, should I delete it?

Comment: That's up to you; it's only meta and thus not as big of a deal as on the main site. If you believe other people might have the same problem, keep it around - if somebody else asks a similar question we now have a duplicate target.

Comment: If you realize that your first question needs to be clarified, you ought to revise that question, not post a second question that's about the same thing.

Comment: @sphanley -- That question is also mine, I'm the OP on both.  I posted this as a follow-up to that.  Meanwhile, things have evolved (you will see that I recently added my own answer to that question), and I plan on deleting this question.

Comment: You can't delete this question, because it has an upvoted answer. That's why it ought to be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a URL, the hash denotes a fragment identifier, or a page anchor. That URL points to some (nonexistent) hash fragment called `-to-vb.net?page=1&sort=newest&pagesize=100` in the [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) tag page. It may not seem immediately obvious because we're all used to the name C#, but since this is a URL, the hash still holds special meaning, and as a result the browser parses it accordingly.

In order for to use the hash in a URL you will need to URL encode it:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-to-vb.net?page=1&sort=newest&pagesize=100
```

Comment: Thanks.  I feel dumb now :)

Comment: @roryap: Happens to the best of us. Well, those of us who are C# developers anyway ;)